# Can you define aliases for imported modules in Python?

Tags: python, module, alias, python-import

In Python, is it possible to define an alias for an imported module?

For instance:

```
import a_ridiculously_long_module_name
```

...so that is has an alias of 'short_name'.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

```
import a_ridiculously_long_module_name as short_name
```

also works for

```
import module.submodule.subsubmodule as short_name
```

Comment: from module  import sub_module_1 as s1, sub_module_2 as s2

Comment: Can you do this for functions too? E.g. `from normal_module import super_duper_ridiculously_long_function_name as supe`?

Answer (score 55):

[Check here](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)

```
import module as name
```

or

```
from relative_module import identifier as name
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try to do `from name import X` (after the alias definition) I get `No module named name`. Can we import modules from aliases?

Comment: It seems you can't, here is the clearest answer I found for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823467

Answer (score 42):

If you've done:

```
import long_module_name
```

you can also give it an alias by:

```
lmn = long_module_name
```

There's no reason to do it this way in code, but I sometimes find it useful in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: For some purposes this is better than the top answers (import long_module_name as lmn) because you can still reference the module by both long_module_name.x  and lmn.x

Comment: This is the technically correct response for the question: aliases for imported modules.

Comment: The reason this is possible is that modules are first-class objects in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, modules can be imported under an alias name.
using **as** keyword.
See

```
import math as ilovemaths # here math module is imported under an alias name
print(ilovemaths.sqrt(4))  # Using the sqrt() function
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **you can define aliases for imported modules in Python**.

Using pandas is considered a ***best practice*** in python because Pandas can import most file formats and link to databases.

**Example:**
Import pandas library

`import pandas as pd`

**Explaining:**

**pd**: is the conventional alias for **pandas**.

**NP**: is the conventional alias for **Numpy**.

Using short alias helps keep code **(concise)** and **(clean)**.

Comment: NP in capitals for numpy??

Comment: Sorry, small letters

Answer (score -5):

from MODULE import TAGNAME as ALIAS

Comment: Can you please be more specific? This answer isn't formatted properly, and it doesn't give an explanation.

Comment: The answer doesn't even provide something new