# Python "from xxx.yyy import xxx" error

Tags: python

I'm working with the `PyFacebook` package in Python, and I've seen people mention numerous times that you can write an import statement as follows:

```
from facebook.djangofb import facebook
```

However, it does not work. It states that `facebook.method_name` exists in the `facebook` module, rather than the `djangofb` module. I assume I'm importing the `facebook.method_name` as `facebook`, not that I'm receiving it from the `facebook` package itself.

I'm using Python 2.6.

How can I alias `facebook.djangofb` as `facebook`?

Comment: @qarma: your bounty message makes no sense; it certainly doesn't seem to have any relationship to the question being asked here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is the proper way to alias a module via import:

```
import facebook.djangofb as facebook
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) (it works the same way in [python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#import), but I found the python 3 documentation explained it clearer):

> If the module name is followed by `as`, then the name following `as` is bound directly to the imported module.

So your statement should look like:

```
import facebook.djangofb as facebook
```

and then `facebook.method_name` will work.

Also see [Can you define aliases for imported modules in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706595/can-you-define-aliases-for-imported-modules-in-python) for additional aliasing options

Answer (score 2):

```
from facebook import djangofb as facebook
```

If you're looking to import `djangofb` as `facebook`, that's how you need to do it.

This way, you can access `facebook.djangofb.method_name` like `facebook.method_name`.

That being said, it's more common to give it a non conflicting name, here it would be `fb` or `face`. Something that doesn't override the root `facebook` import.