# Creating a short alias for imported variable - import types.SimpleNamespace as Ns not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Namespaces are widely used in Python, but it appear that creating a namespace has no short form, for example requires the lengthy `types.SimpleNamespace`, with prior `import types`.

So is there a syntax shortcut for creating a namespace?

It is not possible to do `import types.SimpleNamespace as Ns`, since it gives the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'types.SimpleNamespace'; 'types' is not a package
```

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706595/can-you-define-aliases-for-imported-modules-in-python).

Comment: Use  the `as` keyword

Comment: @EquipDev, why is it not possible?. I also don't see anything in your question that states that

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Saw your answer, and found that I had the syntax wrong, so I updated the question, since I can see that it is possible as you wrote.

Comment: I edited back the error message, it is what made this interesting, not the general question, which is a duplicate of 1000 other questions.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: OK, it give others a hit on the error message, and then a solution.

Comment: @EquipDev ah ok, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from types import SimpleNamespace as sn
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is

```
from types import SimpleNamespace as NS
```

---

What you have used erroneously is the

```
 import X.Y as Z
```

that imports a module `Y` from package `X`; it cannot be used with importing variables from within a module.

However for the most cases the two are exactly identical in behaviour when importing modules from packages, excepting the fact that `import X.Y as Z` has strange corner cases at if it is done while the `X.Y` is being imported, which is why the latter is seldom used anywhere.

See the relevant [PEP 221](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/).

Comment: Thanks, found my mistake there, and can see I can make a short form.

Comment: (And PEP is down at the moment, but that ought to be the authoritative link)