# Why can't I import from a module alias?

Tags: python

I just stumbled across this unexpected behavior in python (both 2.7 and 3.x):

```
>>> import re as regexp
>>> regexp
<module 're' from '.../re.py'>
>>> from regexp import search
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'regexp'
```

Of course `from re import search` succeeds, just as it would have before I created the alias. But why can't I use the alias `regexp`, which is now a known module, as a source for importing names?

This sets you up for a nasty surprise whenever there are multiple variants of a module: Say I am still using Python 2 and I want to use the C version of `pickle`, `cPickle`. If I then try to import a name from `pickle`, it will be fetched from the simple `pickle` module (and I won't notice since it doesn't throw an error!)

```
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> from pickle import dump
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(dump)
'.../python2.7/pickle.py'    # Expected cPickle.dump
```

Oops!

Poking around I see that `sys.modules` includes the real module name (`re` or `cPickle`, but not the alias `regexp` or `pickle`. That explains *how* the second import fails, but not *why* python module name resolution works this way, i.e. what the rules and rationale are for doing it this way.

**Note:** This was marked as a duplicate of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module) that has nothing to do with module aliasing: aliasing is not even mentioned in the question (which is about importing submodules from a package) or the top answers. While the answers to that question provide information relevant to this question, the questions themselves are not even similar IMHO.

Comment: because the import mechanic `import X` or `from X import Y` don't check the value of the variable X, it search for a file/folder called 'X'

Comment: Instead of `from regexp import search` and `from pickle import dump`, why not just `search = regexp.search` and `dump = pickle.dump`?

Comment: @suspiciousdog, why _wouldn't_ I use the `from X import Y` form? It's standard syntax and very, very pythonic (just count the mentions in PEP 8).

Comment: Because in your examples, it doesn't work as intended? Your "nasty suprise" scenario simply isn't compelling because there's a clear and simple work-around. And as @jmd_dk [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40823500/6732794), you can't use the same syntax for importing from a static module name and from a variable module name because it's ambiguous: when should Python interpret the module name literally vs. dynamically? The zen of Python says: _In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess_

Comment: The syntax is `import MODULE as NAME`. A module and a name are not interchangeable is the answer. A module is either a file name, `XXX.py`, or a file in the search path that has the appropriate `__init__.py` in it.

Comment: @BrenBarn, how is this a duplicate to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module) you selected? I understand that the answer states "When you use an import statement it always searches the actual module path", which is relevant here; but neither that question nor the accepted answer mention `import .. as` aliasing at all.

Comment: It doesn't mention it explicitly, but the answer is what you just quoted.  "It always searches the module path."  It doesn't search anything else.  The answer there mentions that it doesn't search "module objects".  When you do `import x as y`, you're just getting a module object called `y`, which is not searched, as all other module objects are not searched.  What is searched is always the module path, and not any objects in any namespace.

Comment: I understand the relevance of that answer, but shouldn't _the questions_ be related to close as a duplicate?

Comment: @suspicousdog [sic], I don't think you're getting the concept of "surprise": work-arounds are something you do after you have already been surprised. If it does something you don't intend, and it's not immediately obvious, it's a problem.

Answer (score 25):

## In short:

You can think of the loading process in that way:

You can **load a module** into your program, in the form of a variable. You can **name the variable for using the module** whatever you want. *But,* the **loading process**, is based on the name of the module's file, not "module variables".

---

## Long version:

`import re` creates a global variable named `re` that serves as the "module portal", in the way it provides the ability to use the module operations.

Most alike, `import re as regex` creates such a "portal" under the variable named `regex`.

But, when looking to create such portal and load the module functionality into it, the importer *does not* use such references. Instead, it looks for the module in your python `\Lib` directory, or your current working directory, as a **file** named `re.py` (or whatever is the name of the module you import).

The `import` instructions does not address *variables*, but *files*, like `#include<stdio.h>` in C. They have their "own syntax", and set of instructions, as ruled by the interpreter structure, which is, to that case, the interpretation of `re` as a file name rather than a variable and `as` for ruling the name of the module "portal".

That is why `regex` is an *operation alias* for the portal for `re`, but **not** an *importation alias* for the module (for that purpose you'll have to use the name of the *file*).

- I have used terms like "module portal" and "operation alias" since I have not found any standard terms for these. Most of the modules and importer mechanics is related to the interpreter implementation. In CPython (where the usage of the C API is common among developers), for example, [`create_module`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/module.html#c.create_module) creates modules for the importer (in the form of `PyObject`s) using the provided specifications for the module, and the [`PyModule_NewObject`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_NewObject) and [`PyModule_New`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_New) functions for the module instance creation that bears the module attributes. These can be viewed in the [C API modules decumentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/module.html).
- When I mentioned the term "portal" as a way to reference the variable created by the `import` statement, I meant to refer to it as a *static* portal, not a *dynamic* one. A change in the module file will not reflect in a running program that already imported it (as long as it didn't reload it), as it will load a copy of the module and use it, rather than asking the module file for the operations when encountering need.

---

Here is pretty much how the variable loading goes realtime:

```
>>> import re
>>> re
<module 're' from 'C:\\Programs\\Python35\\lib\\re.py'>
>>> import re as regex
>>> regex
<module 're' from 'C:\\Programs\\Python35\\lib\\re.py'>
```

You can see that `re` is the module **referenced**, and it was **loaded from** the file `C:\Programs\Python35\lib\re.py` (may change depending on where your python is installed).

Comment: Additionally, you can't use `re.find` for example if you do `import re as regexp`, you must use `regexp.find`.

Comment: Can you give any references for the concepts of "module portal" (or "trigger"), and "operation alias"? I don't recall coming across them when reading about Python's principles.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot treat the module name in import statements as variables. If that was the case, surely your initial import would fail because `re` is not yet a declared variable. Basically the import statement is semantic sugar; it is a statement of its own with its own rules.

One such rule is this: The written module name is understood as if it was a string. That is, it does not lookup a variable with the name `re`, instead it uses the string value `'re'` directly as the sought after module name. It then searches for a module/package (file) with this name and does the import.

This is the only situation (**Edit:** Well, see the discussion in the comments...) in the language where this behavior is seen, which is the cause of the confusion. Consider this alternative syntax, which is much more in line with the rest of the Python language:

```
import 're'
# Or alternatively
module_name = 're'
import module_name
```

Here, variable expansion is assumed in the import statement. As we know this is *not* the syntax which was actually chosen for the import statement. One can discuss which syntax is the better one, but the above is definitely more harmonious with the rest of the language syntax.

Comment: I think this answer explains the _why_ / rationale better than the other answers which simply address the mechanics.

Comment: Regarding your update: the `import` statement performs a name binding, so it requires a valid identifier, not just any arbitrary string. Supporting a hypothetical syntax such as `import <string literal or variable>` would suggest more flexibility than is possible. It is in harmony with other syntax involving name-bindings, such as `del`, `global`, `nonlocal`. And if we're suggesting things in hindsight, I would've preferred a more general ability to reference the string of a name being bound, for use cases such as `Record = namedtuple('Record', <...>)`, `uid = data['uid']`, etc.

Comment: I do not agree that `del` and `nonlocal` statements operate on raw identifiers directly, in the same sense as `import`. In the case of the first two, you supply an existing object as the argument (just as with any function call), and some operation is done. In the case of `import`, you supply an identifier which does *not* map to any existing object. You are right in the case of `global`; the identifier also does not have to map to any existing object, making my previous statement "This is the only situation in the language where this behavior is seen" false. I guess we now have two situations

Comment: Also, as you point out, in the `import` statement the identifier is used both for the file name and it is used as the variable name holding the imported module, limiting valid identifiers to those of valid variable names, but this is irrelevant to the argument. One could remove this degeneracy by importing via `re_module = __import__('re')`. This allows forusing modules which are stored in files with filenames which are invalid as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

When from import is used python tries to look in the from file to import what you have requested. This might make it clearer.

```
import re as regexp

from regexp import search
```

This essentially asks python to look in a file called 'regexp' which it can't find. This is why the alias won't work.

Answer (score 1):

To get a definite answer on this you'll have to ask the designers themselves but, I think you're asking the wrong question.

The question shouldn't be: *Why is it done this way?"* but, it should be, what would be the benefit of doing it the way you're asking? Surely it can be done but why should it?

As is the `import` statement is dead simple and *very* intuitive, you give it a file name, it tries to finds load it up. You even get fancy `as` and `from` but, the concept is simply, you write filenames and you let it be.

What would obfuscating it and making it harder understand achieve, the only achievement is making things arguably more complex.

Python has a history of looking for the rationale behind changes to its design, people asking why aren't `function` objects subclassable will get a "Why should they?" reply; this behavior doesn't really have a use-case. As is, the `import` is simple, intuitive and reminiscent of including/using files in other languages.