# Module object not callable

Tags: python, module

This is my folder structure:

```
script.py
api/
   __init__.py
   charts/
         __init__.py
         charts.py
```

In `script.py`, I have:

```
from api.charts import charts
import billboard
```

and the call:

```
charts('Alternative-Songs', '1997')
```

`billboard.py` is not in the above structure because it was installed on my system via `python setup.py install`, and it has the methods for `charts()`, like so:

```
billboard.ChartData(chart_name, date)
```

at `charts.py`, `charts()` was defined using a `billboard.py` method:

```
def charts(chart_name, date):
    chart = billboard.ChartData(chart_name, date, quantize=True)
    return chart
```

but when I run `script.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 70, in <module>
    print (charts('Alternative-Songs', '1997'))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: full stacktrace please...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there you go

Comment: Try putting `from charts import *` in `__init__.py` in `charts/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your folder structure, `charts` directory contains a `charts.py` file.

So `from api.charts import charts` imports name `charts` as a *module*.

Seems that the `charts` module has a function called `charts`. You think you're calling the function but you're calling the module.

just do

```
print (charts.charts('Alternative-Songs', '1997'))
```

(that makes a lot of `charts` if you ask me :))

Answer (score 1):

```
from api.charts import charts
```

imports the module `charts.py` from the `chart` directory under `api`. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823418/why-cant-i-import-from-a-module-alias/) question for modules aliasing and importing)

Now `chart` is a module reference, not the method `charts`.

To call charts, you'll have to use

```
print(charts.charts('Alternative-Songs', '1997'))
```

(method `charts` inside module `charts`).