# How to dynamically import modules?

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror, dynamic-import

I am trying to import modules dynamically in Python.  Right now, I have a directory called 'modules' with two files inside (`mod1.py` and `mod2.py`).  They are simple test functions to return time (ie. `mod1.what_time('now')` returns the current time).

From my main application, I can import as follows:

```
sys.path.append('/Users/dxg/import_test/modules')
import mod1
```

Then, I can execute:

```
mod1.what_time('now')
```

This works correctly.

I am not always going to know what modules are available in the directory.  I wanted to import as follows:

```
tree = []
tree = os.listdir('modules')

sys.path.append('/Users/dxg/import_test/modules')

for i in tree:
  import i
```

However, I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named i
```

What am I missing?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823418

Comment: The above referenced question helps to understand why it does not work; but not if there is a solution to make this work.

Comment: Take a look at the [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function.

Comment: This [answer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) of mine shows using `__import__()` with `listdir()`. It's doing more than you want, but that should be easy to fix.

Comment: Q: If you don't know what modules are available, how will your code know to use them?

Comment: @martineau; each module is a test case in this application.  Each module (test case) has a standard layout with a main function called execute_test().  So based on the file name being the module name, we can trigger the test case to execute.  Example : module file name is create_user.py; once imported, we could trigger with create_user.execute_test().

Answer (score 14):

The `import` instruction does not work with variable contents (as strings) (see extended explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823418)), but with file names. If you want to import dynamically, you can use the [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) method:

```
import importlib
tree = os.listdir('modules')

...

for i in tree:
    importlib.import_module(i)
```

Note:

- You can not import from a directory where the modules are not included under `Lib` or the current directory like that (adding the directory to the path won't help, see previous link for why). The simplest solution would be to make this directory (modules) a package (just drop an empty `__init__.py` file there), and call `importlib.import_module('..' + i, 'modules.subpkg')` or use the [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) method.
- You might also review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134). It discusses a similar situation.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve something *like* what you are proposing, but it will involve some un-pythonic code.  I do not recommend doing this:

```
dynamic_imports = dict()
for filename in tree:
    name = filename.replace('.py', '')
    dynamic_imports[name] = __import__(name)
```