# Can't import from a module imported as

Tags: python, import, module

Let's suppose I import the `pathlib` module with an alias :

```py
import pathlib as plib
```

Then `plib` is now pointing to the `pathlib` module :

```py
>>> plib
<module 'pathlib' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py'>
```

Now can someone tell me why importing something from this aliased module doesn't work?

```py
>>> from plib import Path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plib'
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823418/why-cant-i-import-from-a-module-alias

Comment: Thanks, my question is in fact a duplicate of the above link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading process of The module is not based on the alias, it searches the python installation or project directory by the given name after import statement.