# Need to 'import datetime' and 'from datetime import datetime' but this causes an error: redefinition of datetime unused?

Tags: python, datetime, import

I am trying to do both `import datetime` and `from datetime import datetime`, however I am getting a redefinition unused error.

Is there anyway just to import either of them? I tried to delete one, but based on my code it seems I need both?

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Union


def to_date(date: Union[str, int]) -> datetime.date:
    """Convert `date` from `20201130`/`"20201130"`/`"2020-11-30"`to a datetime.date object."""
    date = str(date)
    try:
        yyyy, mm, dd = date.split("-")
    except ValueError:
        yyyy, mm, dd = date[:4], date[4:6], date[6:]
    return datetime.date(int(yyyy), int(mm), int(dd))


def epoch_nanoseconds_to_human_date(date):
    """"Convert an EPOCH nanosecond date to a human readable date"""

    # Converting EPOCH nanoseconds to datetime in seconds
    datetime_in_seconds = datetime.fromtimestamp(date // 1000000000)

    # Convert datetime to human readable date
    return datetime_in_seconds.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

When I run the above, I get `redefinition of unused 'datetime' from line 1`

If I remove the first `datetime` import, then the return statement of the first function `int(mm)` and `int(dd)` is flagged and causes an error.

if I remove the second datetime import, then in the second function `fromtimestamp` causes an error.

Any idea how I can just import one- from my understanding I need both.

Comment: You can import with more granularity with `from datetime import datetime, date` or omit the second import and then use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` in your second function.

Comment: Maybe useful for you [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706595/can-you-define-aliases-for-imported-modules-in-python)

Comment: Thanks guys, i see the issue! - something so basic yet causes such troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like `import datetime as dt` or remove the `from datetime import datetime` line and use it as `datetime.datetime` instead.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use

```
import datetime
```

Where you need the datetime class inside datetime module you can use

```
datetime.datetime
```