# Python 'as' keyword

Tags: python, numpy, syntax

I don't understand why I can't use numpy. after I give it an alias.

I got an error for this.

```
import numpy as np

ar = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])

print(ar)
```

I can only type

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

print(ar)
```

Comment: The whole point of using `as` is so you can use the alias you've given. If you don't want to use `ar = np.array(...)` just do `import numpy` and then you can use `ar = numpy.array(...)` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you define aliases for imported modules in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706595/can-you-define-aliases-for-imported-modules-in-python)

Comment: @Zero I don't think that's really the question. If I understand correctly, OP just wants to be able to use the `numpy` namespace as-is. I suspect they aren't 100% familiar with how imports work yet.

Comment: @JRiggles, I put the link here so OP can get a better understanding of aliasing in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just how the `import ... as` statement behaves. You choose one name for the module you are importing. If you don't have an `as` clause, the module’s own name is used.

If you want to call `numpy` `numpy`, do

```py
import numpy
```

if you want to call `numpy` `np`, do

```py
import numpy as np
```

and if, for some bizarre reason, you want to be able to use either, do

```py
import numpy

np = numpy
```

Comment: Another option if someone wants to use both, for some reason, is to just list both imports, i.e. have both `import numpy` and `import numpy as np`.